# how to insert data in type of Double into phpmyadmin?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, phpmyadmin

I am using eclipse to create an android apps that will read price that entered by user.

The price entered should be storeed into the database (phpmyadmin)

I am using the code below but the eclipse has error and ask me to convert the double to string.

```
            food = Double.parseDouble(inputFood.getText().toString());
            transport = Double.parseDouble(inputTransport.getText().toString());
            tele = Double.parseDouble(inputTele.getText().toString());
            academic = Double.parseDouble(inputAcademic.getText().toString());
            entertainment = Double.parseDouble(inputEntertainment.getText().toString());
            health = Double.parseDouble(inputHealth.getText().toString());
            others = Double.parseDouble(inputOthers.getText().toString());
            budget = Double.parseDouble(inputBudget.getText().toString());

            total = food + transport + tele + academic + entertainment + health + others;          
            balance = budget - total;

           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("food", food));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("transport", transport));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tele", tele));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("academic", academic));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entertainment", entertainment));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("health", health));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("others", others));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("budget", budget));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("total", total));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("balance", balance));

           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_save_expenses,
                               "GET", params);
```

Is it there is any other coding is use to store double data?

Thanks for answering..

Answer (score 2):

Just write your code for adding params in list this way

```
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("food", "" + food));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("transport", "" + transport));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tele", "" + tele));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("academic", "" + academic));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entertainment", "" + entertainment));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("health", "" + health));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("others", "" + others));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("budget", "" + budget));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("total", "" + total));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("balance", "" + balance));
```

This will change your double type to string for this Constuctor and at on serverside convert string to double and store into database

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My program now is no error but the data is still cannot store into database. It is end up with "Unfortunately, the system has stopped"